# Self-contained primer on species of elementary particles

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, quarks, elementary-particles, subatomic

I'm studying for the GRE and noticed that all my knowledge of elementary particles is purely hypothetical: i.e., I can calculate counterterms for a pseudoscalar Yukawa theory, but I don't actually know what the heck a "baryon" is, what quarks a proton is made of, etc.

Does anyone have recommendations for a concise crash course on the basics of the Standard Model supposing one already knows the principles of quantum field theory? What I'm looking for is essentially just a systematic review or dictionary to couple my knowledge of hypothetical particles (e.g. a Dirac fermion charged under a $U(1)$ symmetry) with that of the actual standard model (in this case, an electron). Thanks!

Comment: this may help for the proton https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/largehadroncolliderfaq/whats-a-proton-anyway/

Comment: This is elementary, but a good list. http://www.pas.rochester.edu/~pavone/particle-www/lectures_JFS_files/High%20School%20Lectures/Adam%20Harrington%27s%20Standard%20Model%20Talk,%20%2702-%2703.pdf . As I know the author is a good teacher maybe this will help https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.6779